# PayPal simple Subscribe and Unsubscribe

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a page that will have a monthly subscription fee and I was wondering if PayPal's simple subscribe and unsubscribe buttons can do the trick without using the API.
On subscription the user is returned to my page and I handle the subscription, but if the user decides to unsubscribe how can I handle it? Or is it possible at all?
Does the page make a return call to the same address I have given for redirection?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Standard Subscription buttons can be used without any API calls.  I would recommend using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to handle all transactions associated with subscription profiles.

PayPal's IPN server will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server when transactions occur in real-time.  This allows you to automate post-transaction procedures like updating your database, sending email notifications, or anything else you might like to do when transactions occur.